# Java interfaces - reference interface points to another interface's method. Where is that method defined?

Tags: java, interface, jdbc

I understand how interfaces work in general but I am confused about a thing. I started learning about JDBC and I can't understand this statement:

```
Connection conn = null; // set a reference pointing to nothing
Statement stmt = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection('mysql/derby/other db', 'user', 'password');  

//This is what I don't understand
stmt = conn.createStatement(); // Interface reference calling another interface's method
// Or this
preparedStmt = conn.preparedStatement("INSERT INTO db.table values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

I have a *Statement* interface reference pointing to another interface's method *Connection* interface. Where is this method defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can have variables that are of interfaces types (e.g. `Connection`, `Statement`, ...), the actual objects at runtime need to be of some specific implementation type.

For example `DriverMananger.getConnection()` takes over the job of finding the `Connection` implementation that can handle the JDBC URL you provided.

Let's assume that it's the fictional `MyDBConnection` class (that implements `Connection` of course).

Now your `conn` variable holds a reference of to a `MyDBConnection`.

When you call `createStatement()` on that object, it's actually `MyDBConnection.createStatement()` that gets executed. That method *could* look like this:

```
public Statement createStatement() {
    return new MyDBStatement(this.someConnectionState);
}
```

After this, your `stmt` variable would hold a reference to a `MyDBStatement` object.

Remember: if any method promises to return something of type `A`, it can equally well return something of a sub-type of `A` (i.e. either a sub-class of `A` or a class implementing `A`, if `A` is an interface). In fact, when `A` is an interface it **has to** return a class implementing `A`. Since a pure `A` object can't exist.

Comment: I was looking in the JDK source (Connection, Driver and DriverManager classes) where I could find the Connection implementation in order to justify the contruction of the objets and its return, but I didn't find it. At the end, where is the Interface Connection implemented in order to provide the Connection objet??

Comment: @jomaora: the actual implementation is in the JDBC driver of each specific database (i.e. there's one for MySQL, one for Oracle, one for MS SQL Server, ...)

Answer (score 1):

getConnection indicates that it returns an object of type Connection. So it can return any type which extends Connection.
So preparedStatement is a method defined in the Connection interface but implemented in one of its subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of "pointing to another interface's method" and "defining method of interfaces". An interface in Java is just that: it defines an *interface* to call methods of other objects without having to now details of these objects, like you don't have to know how the keys on your keyboard work when pressing them. (In fact, the public constructors + methods of classes unknown to you form an *interface* just the like.)

In this case, you know that the DriverManager by some magic creates a object which (bzw. whose actual class (unknown to you)) implements Connection. This includes implementing the methods `createStatement` and `prepareStatement`. What you are doing there is not assigning the `stmt` *reference pointing to another interface's method*, but calling (invoking) this method and let your reference point to the object returned by this method.